# Sharing code between the Editor and the Kotlin REPL in Intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

I am a longtime *PyCharm* user in which we can:

- select some snippet in the current Editor pane
- invoke `Execute selection in Python Console`.
- Repeat the first two steps while retaining the same `python console` and context

I am running into multiple issues / deficiencies in trying to replicate that behavior with *kotlin* in Intellij (Ultimate 2020.3).

- There does not appear to be any equivalent along the lines of `Execute selection in Kotlin REPL`
- So I tried to just do a manual cut and paste but then when invoking "Kotlin REPL" it starts a *new* REPL each time.

[image]

That breaks continuity .

The only *kotlin* related configurations I see are :

[image]

So what is the closest equivalent to the `Pycharm` python console for the `Kotlin REPL`. And how is that configured?

Comment: This feature is not implemented, please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11409 for updates

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov Thanks  - please feel free to make this an (authoritative) answer.